# An English teacher

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

How can I differentiate these two sentences?

> - **He is an English teacher**(=*a person who teaches English*)
> - **He is an English teacher**(=*a teacher who is English*)

EDIT: Yes, I can rephrase this sentence *"He is a teacher of English"* is possible. But just in case, it's not me who says this, is there any possible way to interpret the meaning of the sentence. Somebody told me it's a matter of a stressed word, but he could not clarify that.

Comment: Just rephrase the first to He's a teacher of English.

Comment: @SovereignSun Too long to be spoken. And it sounds awkward to my ears.

Comment: It's as long as the original and is perfectly correct.

Comment: @user178049  SovereignSun's answer is exactly how a native speaker might make the distinction:  "*He* is a teacher of English, while *he* is a teacher from England".  If this is not sufficient, please edit your question to clarify what kind of answer you need.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for the response and I believe you as native speaker. But, see my edit.

Comment: @user178049 thanks for the edit.  I agree that sometimes you may be able to distinguish one meaning from another by emphasis, for example if I put the emphasis on *English* or the emphasis on *teacher*.  However here it doesn't help much because "English" applies equally to both the nationality and the language.

Comment: In spoken english, the sentences would be accented differently. A teacher from England would be, "English TEACHER" and a teacher of English would be, "ENGLISH teacher".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sentence is what is known as an **ambiguous sentence**. Taken on its own, the sentence

> He is an English teacher.

can either mean

1. a person who teaches English.
2. a teacher from England.

Both interpretations carry equal weight - as a standalone sentence there is no way of telling which meaning is correct. One can argue that when spoken, inflection and sentence stress can allow you to differentiate between which meaning of the sentence is inferred.

> He is an **Eng**lish teacher. (he is a person who teaches English.)
>
> He is an English **tea**cher. (he is a teacher from England.)

In many cases I agree that this can be true, however I don't believe it can be treated as a blanket rule, particularly if the speaker is speaking in a neutral tone.

However, the key phrase above (in my opinion) is *'taken on its own'*. Rarely do we encounter these sentences as stand-alone sentences in real life - they are usually part of a much larger conversation, and as the saying goes, context is key.  In real world situations we interpret meaning as part of a bigger picture - for example, if I were in the school staff room and was being introduced to the faculty, I can't think of any situation where 'John is an English teacher' would refer to anything other than the subject that John taught. The context of the conversation as a whole has led me to that conclusion, rather then the five words of that particular sentence.

In some ways, these examples are somewhat contrived, more to highlight the possibility of ambiguity, than to reflect any genuine real world confusion. Consider the following example:

> I saw a man on a hill with a telescope.

1. There’s a man on a hill, and I’m watching him with my telescope.
2. There’s a man on a hill, who I’m seeing, and he has a telescope.
3. There’s a man, and he’s on a hill that also has a telescope on it.
4. I’m on a hill, and I saw a man using a telescope.
5. There’s a man on a hill, and I’m sawing him with a telescope.

In real life we would work out the likelihood of what the speaker intended, based on the conversation as a whole.

All that being said, one of the comments in the original post hit the nail on the head. A native speaker would more than likely make the distinction by restructuring his or her sentence.

> 1. He teaches English.
> 2. He's (a teacher) from England.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to distinguish the two sentences even using different intonation, especially since they are word for word the same.

If you were to change the wording then of course there might be a difference.

> He is an English teacher.
>   He teaches English.
>
> He is an English teacher.
>   He is a teacher from England.
>   He is an Englishman and a teacher.